# Xcode: must re-download all of Xcode to get iOS SDK?

Tags: xcode, download, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to update iPhone SDK without having to re-download Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode)

I installed Xcode 3.x from my Snow Leopard DVD.

Then I spent a few hours downloading the update to 3.2.3 via Software Update.

Then I noticed this didn't have the iOS SDK.

Now all I'm finding on developer.apple.com is a 2.28GB file of the full Xcode 3.2.3 app with iOS SDK. 5 hour download for me.

Is there not any way to get just the iOS4.01 SDK?

Comment: Nope. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode

Comment: Thank you -- this question is solved. I can't see how to mark it answered though...

Comment: You can't without anyone answering the question. Just leave the question to die.

Comment: should just be marked as duplicate