# How do I download and install just the iOS SDK?

Tags: xcode, sdk, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to update iPhone SDK without having to re-download Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode)

I just installed Xcode from my Snow Leopard disc which does not include the iOS SDK. The only download I see on Apple's website is that of both Xcode and the iOS SDK (which does not start downloading). I only want to download the iOS SDK as Software Update downloaded the latest version of Xcode for me.

Is there a download of just the iOS SDK?

Comment: This question has been [asked before on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode). Short answer: you can't download the SDK on its own.

Comment: @thyrgle no, should just be marked as duplicate, as Brian noted below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode