# Install iOS SDK to new Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios, sdk

I just bought a new Macbook pro and install the Xcode in the disk to my machine, but, that Xcode only has mac sdk. How can I install other iOS sdk in? I just don't want to wait for redownloading the whole Xcode because with my network connection, it takes me up to 8 hours.

Comment: You will need to get used to redownloading the SDK... You have to download all the 2.5GB of SDK + XCode each time a new iOS version appears

Comment: That's all changed now. Xcode 4 is over 4Gb in size...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to update iPhone SDK without having to re-download Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple's Developer Tools Evangelist, Michael Jurwitz, has stated on many many occasions that the developer tools team are aware of peoples frustrations with not having an incremental upgrade system.

Unfortunately, no matter how aware they may be, nothing has been done about it for as long as the developer tools have been available.

And now that Xcode 4 is available on the Mac App Store, it seems to me that getting an incremental upgrade system is even less likely (although that is just conjecture on my part). I say this because the Mac App Store, like its iPhone counterpart, downloads the new app in full when an update is available.

There is nothing more you can do other than wait for the download, I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 for the information that the appstore will download the new app in full:(

Comment: So, for XCode4, I can install XCode with iOS sdk and Mac SDK, isn't it? Or only 1 for each xcode and I have to have 2 xcodes in my machine?

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way than re-download all sdk. I'm sorry man.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered here before: [Old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode)

And the sad answer is no. You will have to redownload the whole package every time.

Answer (score 1):

Since they just upgraded their Xcode to version 4 (on 9 March 2011) , it's better for you to download the new Xcode.