# Which XCode version supports iOS 4.3.5 sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, ios4

My Mac OS X version is 10.6.8 and currently i am having XCode 3.2.5 installed with iOS 4.2 sdk.

I want to run my application on iOS 4.3.5 sdk simulator.

Which XCode version has supporting iOS 4.3.5 sdk?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks Johan Karlsson. I agree your point.Can u tell me which XCode version will be support iOS 4.3.5 sdk?.Myself i think XCode 3.2.6. Is it Correct?

Comment: I would suggest that you download the latest version, which is 4.2.1 as of today. This will give you access to develop for iOS 5 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode => 3.2.6 should work. However, any XCode 4 version should work as well. You'll have to download the IOS4 SDK manually for those, as the current XCode Packages only include the IOS 5 SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You have a rather old version of Xcode. You should upgrade to Xcode 4.2 and get a new SDK. By default SDK 5 is used. However it is possible to download older SDKs.

Choose `Xcode -> Preferences` and then `Downloads`. Press the `Components`button and you will have access to support for older stuff. Select the components that you want to download in the list.

It is not possible to install the SDK separate from Xcode, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/way-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode).