# xcode 4.5.2 and IOS SDK 6.0 debug not working?

Tags: debugging, ios6, sdk, xcode4.5, device

I have connected Xcode and my device through USB. In Organizer window my device is showing but  near the schema option my device name does not showing for debugging. My Mac OS Version 10.8.2 and Xcode version 4.5.2 and IOS SDK 6.0 and My device OS 6.1.3.

[image]

Fot this i created device id and provisioning profile from my apple developer account and sinked that profile with my xcode.

*Xcode is showing warning like this in Organizer Window:*

The version of iOS on **“MydeviceName”** is not supported by this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; OS Installed on Your device 6.1.3 (10B329)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your SDK, update the SDK to 6.1 and everything will be fine.

Comment: regarding to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543632/how-to-update-iphone-sdk-without-having-to-re-download-xcode even if its possible its not recommended, just download the SDK+XCode again from the apple developer center.

Comment: As per the above link Xcode-> preferences-> downloads showing only SDK5.0 and 5.1 only. it does not showing any updated SDK like IOS 6.1.

Comment: no, you need to download XCode 4.6 and SDK will come with the XCode

Comment: now only i accepted your answer . while accepting you send this msg dont worry friend thanx a lot